# in sql server when deadlock occured, WHICH transaction will be abort

Tags: sql, transactions, sql-server-2012, deadlock, rollback

when deadlock occurs in sql server, which of transactions will be aborted. I mean what's the plan of sql server to decide which of transactions should be killed!

consider the two transaction below

**Transaction A**

```
begin transaction
    update Customers set LastName = 'Kharazmi'
    waitfor delay '00:00:5'; -- waits for 5 second
    update Orders set OrderId=13
commit transaction
```

**Transaction B**

```
begin transaction
    update Orders set OrderId=14
    waitfor delay '00:00:5'; -- waits for 5 second
    update Customers set LastName = 'EbneSina'
commit transaction
```

if both transaction are executed at the same time, transaction **A** locks and updates *Customers* table whereas transaction **B** locks and updates *Orders* table. After a delay of 5 second, transaction **A** looks for the lock on *Orders* table which is already held by transaction **B** and transaction **B** looks for the lock on *Customers* table which is already held by transaction **A**. So both the transactions can not proceed further, the deadlock occurs.
my question is that, when deadlock occurs, which of the both transaction will be aborted. 
first, i executes transaction **A** then transaction B, sql server aborts transaction **A** and then first executes transaction **B** then **A** the result is the same and transaction A is alorted again. it confused me!
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn the criteria in [SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736.aspx):

> Which session is chosen as the deadlock victim depends on each
>   session's deadlock priority:
>
> - **If both sessions have the same deadlock priority, the instance of SQL Server chooses the session that is less expensive to roll back as**
>     the deadlock victim. For example, if both sessions have set their
>     deadlock priority to HIGH, the instance will choose as a victim the
>     session it estimates is less costly to roll back.
> - If the sessions have different deadlock priorities, the session with the lowest deadlock priority is chosen as the deadlock victim.

For your case, **A** should be considered by DBMS the less expensive transaction to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know just be looking at the queries. Basically, so far as I understand things, the engine considers all transactions involved in the deadlock and tries to work out which one will be the "cheepest" to roll back.

So, if, say, there are 2 rows in your `Customers` table, and 9000000 rows in your `Orders` table, it will be considerably cheeper to rollback the `UPDATE` applied to `Customers` than the one that was applied to `Orders`.